# How to save changes to original excel file using c# interop?

Tags: c#, excel, save, interop, edit

I open file using the following code:

```
object MissingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, MissingValue, false,
            MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue,MissingValue,
            MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue);
```

I tried all following to save and close the file and all of them resulted with COM error as file is a read-only file:

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        Excel.Workbooks wbs = xlApp.Workbooks;
        foreach (Excel.Workbook wb in wbs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(wb.Name); 
            wb.Save();
            wb.Close();
        }

        //xlWorkBook.Save();
        //xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filepath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        //false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        //Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        //xlWorkBook.Close();
        //xlWorkBook.Close(true, filepath, filepath);
        //xlWorkBook.Close(false, MissingValue, MissingValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

I was wondering what could be wrong as I referenced couple other questions that has been asked. Please help!. Thank you for your time.

Comment: file is a read-only file. How can you save a read only file? First make it unreadonly and then save or you can save with other name.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal it is not a read only file, it is probably locked for some reason. Either Open is not right or save is not right

Comment: I figured out a solution with different approach. I created an interface with methods to allow only one Marshall object created and used between methods at once. Logged everything from this interface , and verified every workbook/sheet saved and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used Excel.range to update desired cell values.
When I release the Range object before others, It succeeded to save and close. Thanks all :)
Release code is below:

```
private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```